# What is the simple way to bind an NSMutableArray to a single Colum NSTableView

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsmutablearray, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

Is there a simple way to bind a NSMutableArray made up of Strings to a Single column NSTableView without creating any new classes?

Answer (score 2):

Make an NSArrayController in interface builder. Bind its Content Array to your mutable array, like so:

[image: Binding]

Then bind your table column to that array controller, like so:

[image: Binding2]

(Note the `self` in the model key path field. That's what makes it work with an array of strings.)

Comment: Hmmm. I hope i am missing something. 
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *stringArray; 
is what i have in appDelegate.h
so i used stringArray instead of array in Pic 1. 
Still i don't see the NSTableView getting populated.

Comment: It worked in a test project. Take a look at this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18362750/bindings-test.zip

Comment: Note that if you do this, you'll need to make the table view read-only. If you want to allow editing your strings, you really should be making your own model class and binding to that.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. The code sample cleared me. I was trying with mutable array.

Comment: I have to use an mutable array - the length of the array might change but not it's string contents. So creating a model class is the only way to bind?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using a view-based NSTableView, you must bind the entire table view (not the column) to the array controller's arrangedObjects. Then, bind the text field's `value` to the containing cell view's `objectValue` property.

This is documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/TableView/PopulatingViewTablesWithBindings/PopulatingView-TablesWithBindings.html).

For cell-based NSTableViews, Amy Worrall's answer is the [correct approach](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/TableView/PopulatingCellTables/PopulatingCellTables.html).